# Electron and React. The build is blank

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-builder

I built an electron application with react and typescript, but this is my first time. I ran the electron-builder but is returned an error referent to the build/electron.js. So, I ran the "react-script build" and then, I ran the electron-builder again. No error is returned, but when I open the application.exe, the screen was blank.

How could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without showing us any output (by [edit]ing your question; what was the error? did you get any other output during build?), this is going to be blindfolded guesswork.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner No, the only error I had was that the file "build / electron.js" was missing, as mentioned in the question, but other than that, I didn't get any errors. When I open the application's executable, it remains blank. I even opened the inspect elements console to see if there were any errors, but no.

Comment: did your `react-script build` is generating files in build folder.and are you sure that you have given the right out path for your electron builder